# Is it possible to update some but not all NuGet packages in Xamarin 3?

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios, xamarin, nuget, xamarin-studio

Xamarin 3 has nice new NuGet features built in.
But now there are only options to Restore Packages or Update Packages.
Update Packages updates ALL NuGet packages in the project.

Is it possible to select which packages to update?
Or use something like the Package Manager Console in Visual Studio?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Xamarin Studio 5.0 you can [update a NuGet package one at a time](http://lastexitcode.com/blog/2014/06/01/NuGetSupportInXamarinStudio5-0/) instead of all of them:

1. In the Solutions window expand the Packages folder.
2. Select a package.
3. Right click and select Update.
4. The package selected will then be updated.

There is no Package Manager Console like the one in Visual Studio where you can type in commands. Hopefully the majority of NuGet features should be available through the user interface itself.